# Why do I get an error message when I use a hyperlink on an MS Access form?

Tags: ms-access-2013

When I click on the hyperlink I created on an MS Access form, I get the error message "Unable to open "".  Cannot download the information you requested."  Normally, to get to this SharePoint site via the url, you have to log in first, but I can't find the url to the login page.  I'm assuming this is why I'm getting the error message.  Maybe not.  Can anyone help me to get this hyperlink to direct me to the proper web page so that I can log in to my SharePoint site?  I don't believe I can use the SharePoint function in Access because that seems to only be about uploading my Access lists to SharePoint and I don't want to do that.  I just want to open a SharePoint site.  That's it.

Comment: Please share the hyperlink to find out more about your problem.

Comment: I cannot share the hyperlink because it is sensitive.  Is there any other way you can help with this?